# How can an app hook into text selection system-wide?

Tags: c#, c++, hook

I'd like to be able to track text selections across any application -- is there a hook to enable this behavior on Win32?

Bonus: Anyone gurus know the equivalent hooks for OS X & Linux?

Comment: Without more information, my first try would be to use the Accessibility APIs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373592%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**SetWindowsHookEx**  will do the trick.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? - I don't see a "Text selection" hook in SetWindowsHookEx...

Comment: you can intercept any mouse gesture or keyboard event at a low-level. when you consider that a mouse selection is a left-button-down-mouse-drag for a particular window, its pretty easy to look for such events on given windows or mouse classes.  windows hooks is just a means to an end,  so as you say, you wont find any "text selection" in the doco.