# Getting selected thing into clipboard c#

Tags: c#, winforms

My question is how I get selected text or marked text into the clipboard (ex. user have selected some text in web and when he presses CTRL + A + S, what he got selected or marked get into the clipboard).

I already setup the keyboard hook and background running so now I need to get selected thing into the clipboard.

I tried to get the answer on web but almost 90% of them is for a textbox and i don't need it for a textbox.

Thank you for all your answers, 
-DF

Comment: Your problem is two steps. Look up [how to get the text of whatever is selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526483/how-can-an-app-hook-into-text-selection-system-wide), then look up [how to put text in the clipboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546016/how-to-copy-data-to-clipboard-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Okay thank you, but the first one is not for c# I think.

Comment: That first link is c#

Comment: look below and see the answer

Comment: I think this is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21501291/4835346
I didn't test it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected text of a `TextBox` through the property `SelectedText`.

You can put something on the clipboard using the static method:

```
Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.SelectedText);
```

And get text from the clipboard (also the one copied into the clipboard in the browser) with:

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsText()) {
    textBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
}
```

See: [Clipboard Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

If you only want to do that on the current form, you can get the current control with the form property `ActiveControl`. But will have to use different methods for different types of controls in order to get the selected text. Controls deriving from `TextBoxBase` have a `SelectedText` property. All controls have a `Text` property. All controls deriving from `ListControl` (like `ComboBox`) have a `SelectedValue` property. `ComboBox` has a `SelectedItem` property.

As you can see, you will have to make experiments and find the strategy which works best.

---

Also have a look into the Object Browser of Visual Studio, especially into the namespace `System.Windows.Forms`.

Comment: Is any option without making a textbox?

Comment: Yes: `Clipboard.SetText("hello world");` and `string s = Clipboard.GetText();`. A textbox is just one example for a text source or text destination.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I think they want to get the text selection system-wide

Comment: Okay Thank You! one more question. How the program will know what is selected?

Comment: Windows does not have a general concept of "selected text". However you might get the handle of the current control on the current window and if this one is a known windows control, you might have a chance to get the selected text. See: [How can I get functionality similar to Spy++ in my C# app?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1967604/880990), this might help.

Comment: What about a function called focus or something?